# WordPress: Custom URLs for pages

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a custom post typed called Uploads on my WP site which (using v3.1) has an index archive at this url: `http://domain.com/uploads`

Now because this is created automatically by WordPress and not using a page like in previous versions of WP I am unable to create a sub-page like so: `http://domain.com/uploads/my-page`

How can I create a page and change it's url to fake it so it looks a child page of uploads?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have just one page ... try creating your own plugin:

[This is for rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
[This is for rewrite params](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)

And do not forget to disable [Canonical redirection](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-wordpress-canonical-url-or-permalink-auto-redirect/)

This is faster then searching for working solution ... just if you have 1,2,3 custom urls.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the url edit function, in edit page?
[image: Edit URL function]

Comment: Yeah but how would I add the /uploads/ prefix to the permalink I supply?